# Insertion of character in an initialized array

Tags: c++, c

Let the array I have declared be:

```
char input[] = {'a','l','d'};
```

Now, I have to insert another character inside this array. Can I insert my character inside this array, or do I have to change the size of the input array and then insert?

Do `char input[] = {'a','l','d'}` and `char input[3]={'a','l','d'}` both have the same meaning, or in the first case is the size of array not fixed?

What do I have to do if I want to replace all characters in my array with `'3', '.', '1', '4'`?

Comment: Both are the same. You can't add more elements, the size is fixed.

Comment: **all** C named objects are *always* fixed in size at the site of definition.

Comment: If you want an "array" whose size can be changed, look to `std::vector`.

Comment: @eerorika oops fixed the obvious mistake, thanks.

Comment: Notice that you've also tagged two distinct programming languages in the question. Also, the question kind of lacks the motivation of insertion of a character and if it did then it would almost certainly be a duplicate of some existing question

Comment: To your edit: 3.14 is not a `char` type, it is a `double` so you cannot store it into your existing array at all.

Comment: @jkb ok but if I store 3 . 1 4 individually as a character then it can be store in array

Comment: If you are using c++ you probably want to switch to using `std::string`  instead of compile time fixed sized character arrays and use [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/replace) to replace.

Comment: @drescherjm The OP's character array is just that. It does not appear to be a C-style string since it is not nul-terminated.

Comment: @Abhinav1036 yes you can store the individual characters into an array of `char`, but not in an array with a size of 3. You would need to create a separate array, or use an `std::vector` instead. Unless what you are trying to do is create a string, in which case your array needs to have `'\0'` as its final element, or you can use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have

```
char input[] = {'a','l','d'};
```

then the array is of size exactly 3, and there's no possibility to store additional characters in it.

You can overwrite:

```
input[1] = 'n';
```

but that replaces a character, not insert.

If you declare the array with some extra size, then you have some wiggle room.

```
char input[10] = {'a','l','d', '\0'};
```

Now we have room for 10 characters, and null termination to make it a proper string, so we can easily print it:

```
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = ald".

Overwrite a character:

```
input[1] = 'n';
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = and".

Add a character at the end:

```
input[3] = 'y';
input[4] = '\0';            /* since we just overwrote the old one */
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = andy".

Slide some characters to the right, to make room for new ones

```
for(int i = 4; i >= 2; i--)      /* move two characters, and \0, to the right */
    input[i+1] = input[i];
input[2] = 'o';
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = anody".

Another way to move characters is with `memmove`:

```
memmove(&input[4], &input[2], 4);    /* move three characters, and \0, two to the right */
input[2] = 'y';
input[3] = 'b';
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = anybody".

But this is all very fussy and error-prone.  Examples like I've shown can teach you how characters, arrays, and strings work in C, but they're hard to get right, and I wouldn't necessarily recommend that you write code like this to manipulate your own strings.

---

If you want to replace *all* characters, it's easy enough, as long as you're sure there's room.  Just use `strcpy`:

```
strcpy(input, "3.14");
printf("input = %s\n", input);
```

This prints "input = 3.14".

You have to be careful when calling `strcpy`, though.  The destination array has to be (a) writable and (b) big enough.  If you wrote

```
char input2[3];
strcpy(input2, "3.14");      /* WRONG */
```

that would be wrong, because `input2` is not big enough.  And if you wrote

```
char *input3 = "hello";
strcpy(input3, "3.14");      /* WRONG */
```

that would be wrong, because `input3` is now a pointer, that points to an unnamed array containing the string "hello", and while it's big enough, it's probably an unwritable constant string.

Answer (score 2):

> `char input[] = {'a','l','d'}` and `char input[3]={'a','l','d'}` do both have same meaning

Yes, they have the same meaning.

> now I have to insert an another character inside this array

> I have to change the size of the input array

It is not possible to change the size of an array or to insert elements into it. The size of an array remains constant through the lifetime of the array.

> can u please tell me what to do to insert new character in the same array

You don't, because you can't.

In C++, I would recommend using the `std::string` class to represent a character string that can change size. A minimal example:

```
std::string input = "ald";
input.push_back('i');
```

Comment: can u please tell me what to do to if i want to replace PI characters in my array with 3.14

Comment: @Abhinav1036 See edit.